# How to convert a mysqli_query SELECT into a var

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I'm trying to work out how to get the result of an SQL query through mysqli to store as a var.

I essentially want the query to tell me if the particular row for the user (using `$userID`) has a value of `0` or `1` in it's column `isActivated`. It's basically a boolean to tell me if the user is activated already or not.

My query:

```
$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT isActivated FROM `activations` WHERE userID = '$userID'");
```

The result when I dump `$query` is not as I expected, but I also can't work out which field is the result I'm after in order to try and extract it from the array.

```
object(mysqli_result)#2 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(1) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(1) ["type"]=> int(0) }
```

How would you go about getting the value of the column `isAcivated` and storing it in a var (such as $query or maybe $isActivated would be better)

Comment: Check out http://codular.com/php-mysqli, the result you dump is not what you expect, but it is what php is expected to return..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply do this:

```
$row = $query->fetch_assoc();
$var = $row['isActivated'];
```

that should do the trick

Comment: How would you do this procedurally? Just because all my code so far is procedural it would make sense to stick with one...

Comment: yes it is, its compatible with both OOP and Procedural. For more information on Mysqli, here is a link that'll help you further: http://www.pontikis.net/blog/how-to-use-php-improved-mysqli-extension-and-why-you-should

Comment: @Nick +1 for this nice link

Answer (score 1):

**Try this and read the comment.**

```
 $query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT username, isActivated FROM `activations` WHERE userID = '$userID'")//Select also username 
        or die(mysqli_error());//add this line if your query fail it wil give an error

if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){//if its greater than zero means user exist. 
    $row=  mysqli_fetch_array($result);//fetch the result
    $user_name=$row['isActivated '];
    if($user_name==1){//if the isActivated column is set to one
        echo 'user is activatated'; //or return TRUE its up to you
    }else {
        echo 'user is not activated';//or return FALSE 
    }

}
```

Comment: Sorry you've lost me, what's the point of username? There is no username column in this table.